# Implications of using aggregate value of target variable to predict granular value

Tags: machine-learning

Using a retail example. Say, we're looking to predict price of different product SKUs and we are given aggregate data such as total sales of the product.

Our target variable is granular version of this aggregated value. My question is,

1. Is it recommended to use this aggregate data, total sales of the product in our model to predict the price of the SKU?
2. What are some implications of including this in our variable?
3. Do we need to add a penalty term with this?

Assume, we have a bunch of other features that have some predictive power.

Comment: Aggregate in what sense? Over time? Over products?

Comment: @frank Aggregate as in predict total revenue of a retail store and including variables like price of each SKU in the model.

Comment: @frank like an independent variable is basically a subset of the dependent variable.